# Hide current component before rendering component linked to Navlink - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, render

I am building a single page web app based on react routing where I want to Hide current component before rendering the next component that is supposed to render after clicking on Navlink just like `<a href="someLink">` in html. However, my current component doesn't disappear and the next component renders on the same page next to the current component.

my code for app.js (Main file where parent class renders)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Parent} from './Parent';
import {  BrowserRouter as Router,  Route,  NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Router>
        <NavLink to="/Edit">Edit</NavLink>
        <Route path="/Edit" component={Edit}/>

      </Router>
      </header>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my code for parent.js -

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Child} from './Child';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,  Route,  NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      } 
    render(){
       return(
        <div>
       <p>Parent Render</p>
        <Router>
        <NavLink to="/Parent/Child">Child</NavLink>
        <Route path="/Parent/Child" component={Child}/>
        </Router>
)
     }
}
export {Parent}
```

Child.js

```js
import React from 'react';
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

      } 
    render(){
        return(
         <div>
             Child Render
             </div>
        )}
}
export{Child}
```

There is no problem in app.js. The problem is that when child navlink is clicked, parent does not disappear

Comment: Is the Parent being rendered on some route? Looks like if it is mounted it'll always render since it contains itself another router for its children. Perhaps if you move all (or most) of your routing logic to a single component, like `App`, it can then match and render components correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach it would be to wrap your App.js component with BrowserRouter inside your index.js file like this.

```
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And subsequently, you can update your App.js component with all the routes you desire to have by wrapping all the components within the `Route` component like this.

```
//App.js
import React from "react";
import { Parent } from "./Parent";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Home './Home'
import Edit from './Edit'
import Parent from './Parent'


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/Edit" component={Edit} />
        <Route path="/parent" component={Parent} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now you don't have to wrap your child components with `<Router />`, you can create as many `<Routes />` in App.js and use `<Link />` to navigate to that links.